# How to check if file exists while downloading from server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, epplus

I have an excel sheet written and saved in the server and then downloading to the server using the following code

```
            byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(excelPath);
            System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.ClearHeaders();
            context.Response.ClearContent();
            context.Response.AppendHeader("content-length", fileBytes.Length.ToString());
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            context.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "Export.xlsx");
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
            context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

The file gets downloaded in downloads.
Now I want to know whether we can check the file with same name exists or not?If so delete and then download the file

Comment: There's no need to check whether the file exists, you just need to transfer the file to the client side, then the browser will handle the rest..

Comment: It is renaming the file as (1),(2)..... so on.I want to have only the latest file in their downloads.Is that can be achievable? @User2012384

Comment: No, you can't, website cannot access the computer's directory...

Answer (score 1):

You can try as below

```
System.IO.File.Exists(excelPath)
```

Comment: Does the server recognizes the users local path, when they are accessing it @Harry Quake

Comment: OK, I get it. There is no way to know whether users already have the same name file in their downloads. And the web application cannot directly operate on users' PC. Normally browsers will rename the file with same name as FileName (1).pdf. In some cases, users may select to overwrite the existing one.

Comment: Yeah, It is renaming the file as you said. Can I know how to overwrite the file

Comment: It is totally users' choice. They can save target as and choose to rewrite the existing file.